# Django raw SQL query - looping over args and then using it in query

Tags: sql, django

I have this code:

```
           class AllData(APIView):

            def get(self, *args):

               with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                "SELECT authapi_user.id, authapi_tweet.created_on 
                 FROM authapi_tweet 
                 INNER JOIN authapi_user 
                 ON authapi_user.id = authapi_tweet.author_id 
                 ORDER BY created_on DESC;")
```

I want the conditional part 'On' to match all the author_id's that will be passed through from *args. I know how to use the args data in the query but how can I dynamically change the number of conditions it's going to check so it iterates through all author_ids?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get parameters from query_params like this:

```
self.request.query_params.get('') # get any parameter
```

if `args` variable contains author_ids, you should create where clause:

```
where_clause = f"({' , '.join(args)})"
```

and now change your query like this:

```
f"SELECT authapi_user.id, authapi_tweet.created_on 
             FROM authapi_tweet 
             INNER JOIN authapi_user 
             ON authapi_user.id = authapi_tweet.author_id 
             where authapi_tweet.author_id in {where_clause}
             ORDER BY created_on DESC;"
```